# Looking for a way to automatically replace shortcuts typed in the address bar of a webbrowser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, redirect, hosts

I visit a lot of subreddits and was looking for a way of being able to type just r/subreddit instead off www.reddit.com/r/subreddit, so it has to recognize the r/ pattern and redirect it.
I use mostly firefox but also chrome.
I was hoping to be able to set up something in my hosts file or something similar, but was unsure what exactly to do.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use bookmarks? I have the same problem with Chrome, it wants to search everything, even though it knows my history and could just give me the url I've already used. Annoying.

Comment: I don't really want that many bookmarks with the number of different sites I'd like to shortcut. It isn't that I visit the same ones all the time, but that I'm going to different ones a lot. Reddit Enhancement Suite has a top bar that you can bookmark specific subreddits, but I would also like to use this for other sources besides reddit.

Comment: It's a difficult one. I think bookmarking would be a lot easier than messing with your hosts file, personally, I've only used that to point to different ips, rather than any sophisticated filtering such as that which you propose.

For this and a few other reasons (hangs, broken redirects) I actually went back to Firefox

Comment: The hosts file was just where my mind went first, but I'm open to anything really.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome has excellent solution for this - [Omnibox API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/omnibox.html)
You can bind your own keyword (e.g. "r"), make options list and then redirect to any url you want.

Comment: this is great, I'll try this out and may result in me finally switching from firefox to chrome.